# Firestore Query crashes while using whereNotEqualTo and multiple orderBy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use multiple `orderBy` and `whereNotEqualTo` operators. But the app crashes every time.

May I know why this is happening?

This is my query:

```js
Query q = collectionReference.whereNotEqualTo("uid", uid).orderBy("age").startAt(18).endAt(28).orderBy("geohash").startAt(b.startHash).endAt(b.endHash);
```